# Haskell IO cli menu for small twitter client

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a really simple twitter client with haskell , and to make things simple i was trying to make a simple putStrLn and getLine (i dont know if this is the best solution for the problem or not, i'm fairly new to haskell).

I wanted to do something like this but the output types are different so its gonna give a massive error :

```
main:: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "1)Tweet\n 2)Timeline\n 3)DM\n 4)Inbox\n"
  numero <- getLine 
  if(numero == 1 ) 
      then do  
          frase <- getLine
          tweet frase 
      else
          if(numero == 2)
              then do 
                  frase <- getLine
                  timeline frase
          else 
              if(numero == 3)
                  then do
                        frase <- getLine 
                        nome <- getLine
                        dm frase nome
                  else 
                     if(numero == 4)
                            then
                                 inbox
                            else do 
                                  PutstrLn "Invalido"


tweet :: String -> IO (Either String Tweet)

timeline :: String  -> IO (Either String [Tweet]) 

dm :: String -> String -> IO(Either String DM)

inbox :: IO(Either String [DM])
```

And like i explained above its gonna give you errors like :

```
  Main.hs:86:25: error:
   Couldn't match type ‘Either String DM’ with ‘()’
    Expected type: IO ()
      Actual type: IO (Either String DM)
```

and :

```
Main.hs:75:11: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘Either String Tweet’ with ‘()’
  Expected type: IO ()
    Actual type: IO (Either String Tweet)
```

If someone has an ideia out to solve this particular problem it would be very appreciated .

Comment: Please post all the relevant code and error messages. It's hard to help you if your post does not provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Mephy added some examples

Comment: There's a typo in the question. `PutstLn` should be `putStrLn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your IO action returns a value, like `inbox :: IO(Either String [DM])`, but you want to use it where it needs to be an `IO ()` you can ignore the returned value and follow it with a `return ()` which has the type `IO ()`.

```
  if(numero == 1 ) 
      then do  
          frase <- getLine
          tweet frase 
          return ()
      else
          ...
```

---

Aside: you can simplify the indentation for this by using a [`case` expression](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) instead of nested `if ... then ... else`s.

```
main:: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "1)Tweet\n 2)Timeline\n 3)DM\n 4)Inbox\n"
  numero <- readLn
  case numero of
      1 -> do  
          frase <- getLine
          tweet frase 
          return ()
      2 -> do 
          frase <- getLine
          timeline frase
          return ()
      3 -> do
          frase <- getLine 
          nome <- getLine
          dm frase nome
          return ()
      4 -> do
          inbox
          return ()
      otherwise -> do
          putStrLn "Invalido"
```

I've also replaced `getLine :: IO String` with `readLn :: Read a => IO a`.

Comment: I can't thank you enough , very well explained ,10 out of 10